# Redirect all requests to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a root folder */var/www/minus_project* and only two files in it: *index.php* and *.htaccess*.

How to make apache2 redirect all requests like *localhost.com/minus_project/**some/url/here/...*** to index.php?
My apache2 configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Alias /phpinfo /var/www/phpinfo
        Alias /minus_project /var/www/minus_project

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you create an alias and route everything to `index.php` inside aliased directory.

```
Alias /minus_project /var/www/minus_project

<Directory /var/www/minus_project>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /minus_project/

   RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L,NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

Place above snippet inside `VirtualHost` section and don't forget to restart Apache server.

Comment: Please note that `<Directory>` containers are only valid (or actually necessary) in main `.conf` files, not in `.htaccess` files. The question is kind of vague about it.

Comment: True, even `alias` cannot be used in `.htaccess`

Comment: All right, except I have run **sudo a2enmod rewrite** command before restarting apache.

Comment: do u mind taking a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77879577/7543162) please?

Comment: Sure, I will check