# PHP get and post requests

Tags: php, node.js

i am new to PHP so do not judge me.

I have to make a login/register page using PHP/apache/MySQL (WAMP), and i have some issues with post/get requests. I am coming from java script + node and i am looking for something similar with "app.get("route", callback function) and app.post("route", callback function)" so I can keep my main file with all get/post requests.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a routing engine. You'd have to do some research, but I believe there are such things as standalone items for PHP, or if you use one of the popular frameworks then routing is bulit into most/all of them - depends if you'd want all the other stuff which comes with those as well

Comment: I second @ADyson's point, You probably need to do a lot of research since I'm assuming you haven't used `apache` alongside with `node.js`. I think the very first step you might want to do, is to figure out how to route every path from a domain to a single `php` file using apache, This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046605/redirect-all-requests-to-index-php